# How install a driver without installer tools

Tags: linux, makefile, driver, apt-get, dpkg

I would like to install a WIFI driver on my system but I don't know how.

I'm running a Linux OS: `uname -a`

> Linux computer 2.6.37+ #854 Fri Jul 31 13:26:15 AEST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux

And when I'm trying to run the command `make` I got this error:

> -sh: make: not found

I read many post about a path missing in the **PATH** variable but everything seem to be alright `echo $PATH`

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

And I can't run these command `apt-get` or `dpkg` to install make package.
The Linux OS was built for an embedded system that why is a very light system.

So what is the way for me to install and run a driver in these conditions?

Comment: The apt commands would only work on a debian based system.  If all you have is the source for the module, you'll need the full build chain required to build whatever version of the kernel you are running.  You'll also probably want the (modified?) sources for your existing kernel, as well as the config file (check /boot/config-* for a matching version number).   More info is needed... and this should probably be over on stackexchange... it is system admin related stuff, not programming

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, we need to do cross-compiling on host for the binary which was needed on embedded device.

To set-up cross-compiling env on host, you need arm toolchain which should be available from the vendor website of your embedded device.

To be simple, you can also try to run linaro rootfs(http://www.linaro.org/developers/) on your device, which can provide build env on arm-based embedded device.